# Java swing move an object from one location a to b then from b z

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently working on Uniform cost algorithm "Calculates the shortest path". Why i've mentioned this because it gives me a series of locations on map "GUI"

For example: running `UCA(V1,V4)` would return an array of locations'
let's suppose it returns `V1 V2 V3 V4` shortest path from V1 to V4.

& let's suppose V1,V2,V3, and V4 located at

```
V1.setBounds(10, 10, 50, 50);
V2.setBounds(20, 10, 50, 50);
V3.setBounds(30, 10, 50, 50);
V4.setBounds(40, 10, 50, 50);
```

What i'm trying to do, let's suppose i have another object let's assume it's a truck object.

This truck is going to visit V1 then go to V2 up to v4 according to `UCA` function, but setting `truck.setBounds(10,10,50,50)` then up to V4 `truck.setBounds(40,10,50,50)`
the truck would move to `V1` and etc... but it will only appear on V4, it will never appears on screen that it has visited V1, V2, nor V3.

I could have use timers i mean when it visits V1 `sleep <- 3 seconds` and so on. 
But this is an inefficient way.

Is there some kind of animation that i can use to move truck object from one location to various locations ?

Comment: Depending on how complex a solution you're after, you could use a time line/key frame based solution like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898536/moving-jlabel-to-other-jlabels-gui/26899099#26899099) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619150/move-image-in-a-spiral-fashion-in-java/28619554#28619554) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433074/jpanel-image-flies-from-the-screen/30433207#30433207)

Comment: Or you could do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041991/moving-a-square-from-a-starting-point-to-the-position-of-a-mouse-click-at-a-fixe/31042775#31042775) or something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32392095/how-to-rotate-a-rectangle-after-reaching-specified-position/32397121#32397121)